# django queryset lazyness and template context

Tags: django, django-queryset

Suppose i have 3 models which is `A` `B` and `C` and a views.py like this :

```
def blahblah(request):
    a = A.objects.all(),
    b = B.objects.all(),
    c = C.objects.all(),
    context = {
      a = a,
      b = b,
      c = c,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

I heard queryset is lazy, so it won't hit the database until we use it. The question is, if i have a template which is only use `a` like this `{{ a }}` and not using `b` or `c`, how many times we hit the database? Is putting a queryset on context and not use it on template trigger the queryset? Thank you, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just once.  If you don't actually retrieve any result from `b` or `c`, the database will not be hit.

Typically, in a template, this might happen when you use a for loop to extract the individual items from the query set, or if you run an additional method like `count`.  But supposing your template ONLY says {{ a }}, then only `a` will actually be queried from the DB, although that's a little bit weird to do if you're using `all`, rather than `get`.

I should also add that you can use the [debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to actually see what queries are executed.